# '@' doesn't work, how to stop echo between if..fi in makefile?

Tags: makefile, sh

I have the following command in makefile:

```
$(OUT)/classes.jar: $(JavaFileList) $(libJars) $(ANDROID_JAR) | $(OutClasses)
    @echo javac: `wc -l < $(JavaFileList)` source files

    if [ $$ENABLE_MV = 'YES' ]; then \
        echo Backup $(OutClasses) to $(OutClasses).bak; \
    fi
```

but it will print the following command each time:

```
if [ $$ENABLE_MV = 'YES' ]; then \
    echo Backup $(OutClasses) to $(OutClasses).bak; \
fi
```

how to stop this? "@" dosn't work in if..fi, this error will occur: /bin/sh: line 1: @echo: command not found

Comment: It seems you're already using the answer: `@`.

Comment: no, if add @ in the if..fi, "/bin/sh: line 1: @echo: command not found" error will occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every logical line must start with a `@` to be suppressed.  A logical line is a physical line plus all subsequent lines that are combined using a backslash at the end of the line.  So in your case, you need the `@` before the `if`, because the previous line (`echo`) does not end in a backslash so this is a new logical line.  You don't need the `@` on the subsequent lines because they are the same logical line (connected with backslashes).

```
$(OUT)/classes.jar: $(JavaFileList) $(libJars) $(ANDROID_JAR) | $(OutClasses)
        @echo javac: `wc -l < $(JavaFileList)` source files

        @if [ $$ENABLE_MV = 'YES' ]; then \
            echo Backup $(OutClasses) to $(OutClasses).bak; \
        fi
```

Comment: I wonder why some versions (centos4) of gmake v3.82 seem to work fine with the extra @echo on a continued line but others (centos5) do not?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got GNU make 3.82 on either centos4 or centos5: centos4 shipped with GNU make 3.80, and centos5 shipped with GNU make 3.81.  In any event, the statement you make cannot be true: no version of any make program I'm aware of will "work fine" if you put a `@` before the echo in the example makefile in my answer.  Make simply passes the recipe to the shell as a string, and the shell will throw an error when it tries to run the command `@echo`.